# Reference layer for stripline / microstrip

Tags: transmission-line, signal-integrity

I have a question. I read everywhere in manuals that for a stripline (or microstrip), the reference layer can be not only the ground plane, but also the power plane. Actually, I had a couple of questions:

1. Do I understand correctly that these layers must have good capacitive coupling in the entire frequency spectrum of the signal, at least in the places of the transmitter and receiver? Power decoupling capacitors often provide this coupling.
2. If the first is true, then for conventional MLCC capacitors, which are put by the power supply, the series self-resonant lies in the range of 10-300MHz (depending on the type-size and rating) and then for the conditional signal in 1GHz, the power plane will no longer be the reference layer ? And there are exceptions, because there is a capacitive connection at the board level, but it is not so easy to evaluate this connection for frequent (without modeling), and therefore, cannot refer on the power plane for high hrequncy

Am I reasoning correctly? Or are there serious flaws in the reasoning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is important to choose high SRF caps with low ESR for the spectrum being used when the power plane is used as a reference.  This can include very thin laminate between the two planes.

These caps tend to have a width greater than the length. Standard MLCC caps are  2:1 ratio in aspect ratio like 805 603 402 while the best microwave caps reduce the inductive length to width ratio <1.

10 pF NP0 caps for 1 GHz and 3 pF for 5 GHz is common.

I found this reading [Link](https://www.digikey.jp/-/media/Images/Product%20Highlights/Y/Yageo/MLCCs/CQ_whitepaper_20170706.pdf?la=ja-JP&ts=a931278f-6f2c-495d-b446-95f4014f1a8a) for reference.

But normally you wouldn’t choose the power plane for an AC reference for GHz + wavelengths unless you had to.